# How to manage mapping models in a REST API

Tags: go

I have a REST API, and for each response I need to map my core models to models I am going to expose in the REST service.

I want to name the models the same, like:

```
package main 

type User struct {
  Name string
  Password string
}
```

And the User struct I want to expose in my API:

```
type User struct {
  Name string
}
```

How do I organize my code so that I don't get name collisions, because when I try this I get an error:

> previous declaration at

If I change the package for my API struct to:

```
package api
type User struct { ... }
```

I get another error

> can't load package: package ... found package main and api

If I am able to seperate the models, how will I reference the other package's model:

```
func mapUserToApi(user User) api.User {
}
```

**So I want to take as a parameter the main.User and return the api.User.**

Comment: Are package main and package api within files that are in the same directory?

Comment: yes, all my files currently are in the main directory using package main.  Since I want my api models to be named the same I need to seperate them into diff packages

Comment: You can't have different packages in the same directory. package is pretty synonymous with directory.
Your api models would need to go in `./api/model.go` and the main package could live in `./main.go`

Comment: Read [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). This document describes how to organize code into packages and use those packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, what you want to do is simply not possible under the same package, and is likely to cause confusion even under different packages. If you want to go ahead and do the latter anyways, you should have a folder called `api` and you can put `user.go` inside of it. A sample folder structure then looks like this:

```
main.go // package main
user.go // package main
/api
  user.go // package api
```

For what it's worth, when I design an API I'll typically have a struct `User` in package `model`, and a struct `UserResponse` in package `handler`. For endpoints that take data, they'll also have a `UserRequest` struct associated with them as well. This makes clear what their purpose is regardless of what package they're being referenced in.